# Searching for an exact phrase with the Microsoft Cognitive Services - Academic knowledge API

Tags: evaluate, azure-cognitive-services

I want to search for academic papers containing the exact phrase "ecopath with ecosim" using the Microsoft Cognitive Services - Academic knowledge API. I suspect that I need to use the W field, but I can't get it to work. Can somebody please give me a pointer? I can't find 'W' field usage examples anywhere.

Attempts that do not work:

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(W==['ecopath','with','ecosim'])
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(W==['ecopath with ecosim'])
```

Thanks,
Jeroen

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query such as:

https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(And(W=%27web%27,W=%27semantic%27),Composite(AA.AuN==%27victor%20saquicela%27))&attributes=Id,Ti,Y,D,CC&subscription-key=f66e8......

When you want form a query that contains some words in title, abstract, etc. you can use And(W='web',W='semantic')

Comment: Thanks Fernando. The 'and' clause requires both terms to be present, but does not guarantee that the terms occur beside each other in a fixed order. I need to search for an actual phrase, not individual keywords.

Is that possible?